# Need help on rocket boots

Tags: candy-box-2

I have been trying to get the rocket boots for hours but all the strategies don’t work, or just take hours to do. Does anyone have an easier way?

Comment: Which strategies have you tried and are struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the boots of introspection, the sponge from the sea, and the summoning tribal spear, you can send out enough minions to make a long line. repeat this process but shorten each stair by 1-3 minions so that you have 2 minions at the top so you can jump on top of the chest before another minion spawns. Then use the sponge to squeeze down from atop the chest and get the loot. If a thing spawns in front of the chest, use the black demons spell to clear all of the minions then try again.